# User Permissions for a schema but not to table

Tags: oracle

Is there any way that i can give permission to a user for accessing the schema of a table but not to the data in the table?? 
Any answers or suggestions are welcome....

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "give permission for accessing a schema"?

Comment: @user2268796 Schema in Oracle speech is a synonym for user, so if you are talking about the DDL statement for the table, you shouldn't use the term "schema" for that - that's really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by schema you mean the DDL statement for the table, here's one way to do it:

```
   -- as table owner
   create or replace function getDDLForTable(table_name in varchar2) 
     return CLOB is
          l_Result CLOB;
        begin
          select dbms_Metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',
                                       table_name)
            into l_result
            from dual;
          return l_Result;
        end;

   grant execute on getDDLForTable to <other_user>;

   -- as other_user
   select <owner>.getDDLForTable('T') from dual
```

The trick is to create a function that returns the DDL statement (as the table's owner) and grant execute privileges on this function to the other user.